# Keep a webpage from rendering in Internet Explorer 7

Tags: html, internet-explorer

I'm writing a program to convert documents into HTML pages.  The source documents can contain embedded images; I'm converting them into `data:` URIs to make the resulting HTML page a self-contained document.

This is where I run into a problem: Internet Explorer before version 8 doesn't support `data:` URIs.  Requiring IE8 or newer is acceptable, but I want to make it clear that IE7 isn't working -- missing images may not be obvious enough.  Is there something I can put in the markup to make older versions render in an extremely broken fashion, or not render at all, without affecting newer versions or non-IE browsers?

I'd prefer to do this through HTML markup rather than Javascript, to ensure it works even if scripting is disabled.

Comment: The <-- if ie tags should work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wrap what you want / don't want in **IE Conditional Comments**.

See [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html) for details...

For example:

```
<!--[if lte IE 7]>
According to the conditional comment this is IE 7 or lower<br />
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score -1):

As has been suggested - the conditional tags for IE should do the trick.

Example:

```
<!--[if lte IE 7]>
<style type="text/css">body{display:none;}</style>
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score -1):

The question asks how to keep the page from rendering in IE7 - my previous answer provides the correct example using CSS to hide the body of the page from IE7 or lower. How ever, after reconsidering the question the actual solution would be to wrap the entire page in the following IE condition:

```
<!--[if gt IE 7]>

<![endif]-->
```

This would prevent the rendering where as my previous answer just hides it. Only IE 8 and above would render the content inside the condition.

Comment: Rather than adding two seperate answers, please update your original answer. Also as your solution almost matches the answer that's most upvoted and been chosen as correct it just looks like rephunting.